model (constraint) sale probability of properties
I am trying to model the probability of a sale of a (vacation rental) property depending and price, property features (quality, size etc.), space and time. I am doing this at daily grain and achieve reasonable F1 scores.
Alas this ends up producing optimistic estimates as I guess it assumes there is unconstraint demand and does not really work at unit but daily “unit type” level. Is there anything I can do?
